# Oozie pig action change guava dependency for job jar

Tags: hadoop, classpath, apache-pig, oozie

How can I configure an oozie pig action to give precedence to the user.classpath ?
Pig version 0.10.0-cdh4.2.1

Have tried all of

```
mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence
mapreduce.task.classpath.first
mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first
mapreduce.user.classpath.first
```

as part of the configuration setting for the pig action.

```
<action name="my_action">
    <pig>
        <configuration>
             <property>
                  <name>mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first</name>
                   <value>true</value>
              </property>
```

But none of them seem to work.
The problem is that pig (somehow) depends on guava 11 and my job depends on guava 13. I want to push my job's jars first in the classpath.
EDIT : I think it is oozie that depends on guava11

Can't get this to work ? any pointers ?

Adding more info :
After going through the logs i see that the

```
mapred.job.classpath.files // has guava13 first in the classpath
mapred.cachefiles // has guava13 first in the classpath
```

However when org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher launches the job; then the JobControl logs for Zookeeper have guava 11 first in the classpath

```
[JobControl] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.class.path= // has guava 11 first in the classpath !
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for oozie/pig/hive

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not for the mapreduce job itself but the oozie launcher, who launches the mapreduce job for you. so you should use the following one instead.

`<property>
     <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first</name>
     <value>true</value>
 </property>`

Answer (score 0):

Below setting should solve your problem.

```
            <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.classloader</name>
                    <value>true</value>
            </property>
```